# Wait asynchronous subscription as variable will created - Angular

Tags: angular, components, observable, angular6, subscription

I have two components: ***map.component*** and ***choose-coordinates.component***. They both are siblings and they are in components folder. I also have a service, that communicates between components.

In ***choose-coordinates.ts*** in ngOnInit method, I get coordinates from my form and send this coordinates to component map using service.

***choose-coordinates.component.ts***

```js
ngOnInit() {
    const cords: Array<number> = [this.pointForm.get('X_WGS84').value, this.pointForm.get('Y_WGS84').value];
    this.mapService.setChangeCords(cords);
}
```

***map.service.ts***

```js
getChangeCords(): Observable<Array<number>> {
    return this.changeCords.asObservable();
}

setChangeCords(cords) {
    this.changeCords.next(cords);
}
```

In ***map.component.ts*** I'm picking up this coordinates and call the method *setView* on element *map*.

***map.component.ts***

```js
this.mapService.getChangeCords().subscribe((cords: Array<number>) => {
    this.map.setView(latLng([cords[0], cords[1]]), 19);
});
```

But in the moment when I want to call method `setView()`, `this.map === undefined` so I can't call method `setView()`.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setView' of undefined

Variable `this.map` is initialized in `onMapReady()` method:

```js
onMapReady(map: Map) {
    this.map = map;
}
```

And this method is in map.component.html (I use ngx-leaflet)

```html
<div
     leaflet
     [leafletLayers]="layers"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
     [leafletOptions]="options">
</div>
```

I want to know if it is possible to stop subscription until variable this.map will be created. I imagine this something like this:

```
this.mapService.getChangeCords().subscribe((cords: Array<number>) => {
    if(this.map !== undefined){
        this.map.setView(latLng([cords[0], cords[1]]), 19);
    }
});
```

Or maybe it is possible to init component *choose-coordinates.component* as the last component - after *map.component*.

Because I want the this.map element to be defined before I call the method `setView()` on it.

Comment: Can you not initialise `choose-coordinates.component` only once the map component has been initialised itself (i.e. when `onMapReady` is triggered)?

Comment: No, because my application is quite complicated. choose-coordinates.component is initialized in two another components and this is not always related to the initialization of map.component. I want to always initialized map.component, but choose-coordinates.component I want to initialize only when go to http://localhost:4200/home/edit/8 link.

Comment: As a workaround you could save the coordinates in your subscribe block if `this.map` is not set, then assign the coordinates in `onMapReady`.

Comment: I can't assign coordinates in onMapReady because onMapReady is called once. I want to initialized and destroy choose-coordinates.component a lot of times. The problem is only when I want to initialized choose-coordinates.component on the first time, when map.component isn't jet created.  When I initialized choose-coordinates.component in another part of my application (not during direct entry from the link) there isn't any problem, because map.component was initialized earlier.

Comment: What I suggested would work in this scenario I think. Saving the coordinates would only be useful the 1st time, IF map component is not initialised. But maybe I did not understand...